# Infinite Video Loop in Ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, rtmp

Is there a way to infinitely loop a video in ffmpeg for a livestream? I've been looking around and can see it was possible to use "loop 1" but it appears that is no longer working.

This is what I'm currently using, but as you can see, it is not infinitely looping and entering a ridiculously high number is not an option for me due to 32-bit integer limitations:

```
ffmpeg -re -f concat -i <(for i in {1..10000}; do printf "file '%s'\n" /root/file.flv; done) -codec copy -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
```

Comment: _Update:_ In my testing, I got `WriteN, RTMP send error 104 (52 bytes)` after a few hours so will probably just call it quits and say Ffmpeg just isn't up to livestreaming. Thanks anyway, folks!

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i file.flv -c copy -f flv rtmp://x.y.z
```

This option is buggy when the input it is applied to is filtered with another input, like in an overlay. For a single input - output chain, it works fine.

Comment: Unrecognized option 'stream_loop'.

Comment: You'll need a ffmpeg build from Oct 2015 or later.

Comment: Oh. How do I get a more recent version? I have Ubuntu 15.04 but it has certainly had updates since October!

Comment: Get them from here: http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: Thanks! I'll download it later today, wonder what on earth a .xz file is then pray this works. Will do it on a server though since that way there's no real chance of upsetting things on my computer such as Openshot. Do you advise uninstalling the repositories version first?

Comment: This is a static build. It won't affect anything else. Just don't put in one of the path locations to avoid it being called by other programs.

Comment: Oh, okay. I've got it.  :P

Trying it soon.

Comment: Just tried it and it outputs the video once, adds a minute to the timestamp for some reason then gets stuck.  :/

Comment: Add `-fflags +genpts` before `-i`

Comment: Same thing is happening. `./ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -fflags +genpts -i ../file.flv -c copy -f flv test2.flv`

Comment: I tested it here. It loops, but the timecode is buggy and jumps 30 seconds after each loop on a 10 second input. Which is to say, it's buggy.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-vf loop=parameters` filter, see [fine documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#loop). Note that this currently will put all video frames in memory.

Comment: The OP will have to re-encode to get the unending output stream. Why does stream_loop not work reliably here?

Comment: There is bug in pts generation form stream_loop I guess.

Comment: In this [question](http://video.stackexchange.com/q/18518/1871), the user would like help on getting an animated zoom for a video input.